# Mimimize dynamically created JSON

Tags: php, json, compression

I am creating some dynamically created JSON (see below script) which is accessed by Ajax on the client.  I don't believe I wish it to be server cached since it will result in a lot of files (i.e. I don't want to use https://code.google.com/p/minify/), but client caching is okay.  How can I minimize the content to improve performance?  My initial thoughts are:

1. Manually modify the initial templates to be minimized.  Only problem I see is harder to edit and troubleshoot.
2. Use something like https://code.google.com/p/minify/ to minimize the pre-parsed file, and server-side cache it.  Haven't yet given much thought about how this might be implemented.
3. Use `ob_start('ob_gzhandler');`  Does this actually remove the white-space, or just change the content into some sort of binary format?  Is it applicable for all content, or just HTML?
4. Use regex or something similar to remove whitespace.  One option is http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php#71953.  Maybe the effort exceeds the benefit of a smaller file?

CODE

```
<?php
function parse($template, array $values) {
    $re = <<<RE
/
    "{ (\w+) }"
/x
RE;
    return preg_replace_callback($re,function ($matches) use ($values) {
        $match = end($matches);
        if(isset($values[$match])){
            if(is_bool($values[$match])){$new=($values[$match]?'true':'false');}
            elseif(is_numeric($values[$match])){$new=$values[$match];}
            else{$new='"'.$values[$match].'"';}
        }
        else{$new=$matches[0];}
        return $new;
        },
        $template);
}

//$template actually gotten from a JSON file
$template=<<<EOD
{
   "rules":{
      "name":{
         "required":true,
         "noInvalid":"{noInvalid}",
         "maxlength":"{maxlength}",
         "minlength":2,
         "somethingelse":"{somethingelse}"
      }
   }
}
EOD;
$values=array('noInvalid'=>true,'maxlength'=>20,'somethingelse'=>"hello");
$json=parse($template,$values);
$json=json_decode($json);
var_dump($json);

?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["rules"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["name"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (5) { ["required"]=> bool(true) ["noInvalid"]=> bool(true) ["maxlength"]=> int(20) ["minlength"]=> int(2) ["somethingelse"]=> string(5) "hello" } } }
```